# Task not serializable when moving simple function out of UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to separate out the functions in the UDF's to write tests, however this is causing serialization type errors? I attempted different formats of creating UDF's but its still not working.

Why does this work?

```
   protected val normalizeDomain = udf {(dealer_url: String) => 
     var domain = if (dealer_url.startsWith("http://") || dealer_url.startsWith("https://")) dealer_url else s"http://$dealer_url"
     domain = new URL(domain).getHost
     if (domain.startsWith("www.")) domain.replace("www.", "") else domain
   }
```

But not this?

```
  def normalizeDomainDef(dealer_url: String):String = {
    var domain = if (dealer_url.startsWith("http://") || dealer_url.startsWith("https://")) dealer_url else s"http://$dealer_url"
    domain = new URL(domain).getHost
    if (domain.startsWith("www.")) domain.replace("www.", "") else domain
  }
  val normalizeDomain = udf[String, String](normalizeDomainDef)
```

When doing the latter I get:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: line9e1150bafcc941e3b83a5f4ad173d2ae122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DealerVDPUrlMaker$
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: line9e1150bafcc941e3b83a5f4ad173d2ae122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DealerVDPUrlMaker$, value: line9e1150bafcc941e3b83a5f4ad173d2ae122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DealerVDPUrlMaker$@131552b)
    - field (class: line9e1150bafcc941e3b83a5f4ad173d2ae122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DealerVDPUrlMaker$$anonfun$3, name: $outer, type: class line9e1150bafcc941e3b83a5f4ad173d2ae122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DealerVDPUrlMaker$)
    - object (class line9e1150bafcc941e3b83a5f4ad173d2ae122.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$DealerVDPUrlMaker$$anonfun$3, <function1>)
    - element of array (index: 4)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 5)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10, name: references$1, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem lies in the fact where your `normalizeDomainDef` lies in. When you use `def`, it means you put it into some class and now the whole instance of that class should be serialized to call that method and probably 
 that class includes a lot of non-serializable stuff. To fix it try putting the function into an independent top-level `object` like this:

```
// top level object
object MyUdfs {
  def normalizeDomainDef(dealer_url: String):String = {
    var domain = if (dealer_url.startsWith("http://") || dealer_url.startsWith("https://")) dealer_url else s"http://$dealer_url"
    domain = new URL(domain).getHost
    if (domain.startsWith("www.")) domain.replace("www.", "") else domain
  }

  val normalizeDomain = udf[String, String](normalizeDomainDef)
}
```

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. I ended up just testing the UDF's themselves by creating local dataframe.

Comment: @NutellaAddict, that's a surprise to me. Could you share the "Serialization stack" for the code like I suggested? I you sure your counterpart of `MyUdfs` is not contaminated by some non-serializable stuff?